# tab content is not shown while clicking other tabs

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, tabs

I am new to creating tabs.I am following the the turtorial in here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-a-slick-tabbed-content-area/

The problem with my tabs is when i click the next tab, all the content is gone

Here is my html;

```
<div class="tabbed_area">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" id="tab1" class="tab active">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab2" class="tab">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab3" class="tab">Exclusive</a></li>
   </ul>

        <div id="content1" class="content" ><p>This is Tab 1</p></div>
        <div id="content2" class="content" ><p>This is Tab 2</p></div>
        <div id="content3" class="content" ><p>This is Tab 3</p></div>

</div>
```

and the Jquery is in here ;

```
$("a.tab").click(function () {  

    // switch all tabs off  
    $(".active").removeClass("active");  

    // switch this tab on  
    $(this).addClass("active");  

    // slide all elements with the class 'content' up  
    $(".content").slideUp();  

    // Now figure out what the 'title' attribute value is and find the element with that id.  Then slide that down.  
    var content_show = $(this).attr("title");  
    $("#"+content_show).slideDown();  

});
```

can anyone find the problem ?

Comment: You don't have any 'title' attribute for `a`!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial is saying you to add a title attribute to the list, otherwise your JavaScript will have nothing to be based in when changing tab. It needs to have something to identify what div content you want to open.

```
<ul class="tabs">  
    <li><a href="#" title="content_1" class="tab active">Topics</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#" title="content_2" class="tab">Archives</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#" title="content_3" class="tab">Pages</a></li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: OMG. What a silly mistake i have committed and could not find it. Thanks alot @Ivo Pereira

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `title` property to the `<a>` anchors:

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#" title='content1' id="tab1" class="tab active">Articles</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title='content2' id="tab2" class="tab">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title='content3' id="tab3" class="tab">Exclusive</a></li>
</ul>//-----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------these titles are important to put
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this simply, using [**Tabs**](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/):

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ fx: { height: 'toggle', duration: 500 } });
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tYyBC/2/)